# Reading Kmeans data and chart from R

Tags: r, data-visualization, k-means

I performed and plotted a kmeans analysis in R with the following commands:

```
 km = kmeans(t(mat2), centers = 4)
 plotcluster(t(mat2), km$cluster)      #from library(fpc)
```

Here is the result from the plot:[image]

What I want to know is how to make sense of the `km$centers` attribute and the plot. What I know is that `km$centers` is a 4 X 31 matrix. Each row represents the corresponding cluster. I think each column represents an iteration in the algorithm (correct me if I am wrong) so the final iteration and result of the algorithm for the centers would be given by:

```
km$centers[, 31]

 0.008785652 -0.088641371 -0.012666252 -0.079348292
```

I must be wrong about a lot because this leads to the following questions:

1. The centers given by`km$centers` are not (x, y) coordinates. How do I get these (x, y) center coordinates?
2. The center for cluster 4 (according to the plot) must be something like (12, 2) but the above center numbers do not reflect any of these coordinates. In fact every number in the 4 X 31 matrix is less than 1. So, what is the relationship between `km$centers` and the plot?

The ultimate goal here is to create a matching (not mentioned here) based upon the (x, y) coordinates.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this question better suited for StackOverflow?

Comment: I think it's just on our side of the line since the problem looks to be a confusion about what the "center" means.

Comment: reproducible example please? http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting hung up on the difference between the center of the actual cluster vs. the center of the 1s, 2s, etc. on your plot.

The actual center of your cluster is in a high-dimensional space, where the number of dimensions is determined by the number of attributes you're using for clustering. For example, if your data has 100 rows and 8 columns, then `kmeans` interprets that has having 100 examples to cluster, each of which has eight attributes. Suppose you call:

```
km = kmeans(myData, 4)
```

Then, `km$centers` will be a matrix with four rows and eight columns. The center of cluster #1 is in `km$centers[1,:]`--the eight values there give its position in the 8-D space. Cluster #2's center is in `km$centers[2,:]` and so on. If you had eighty attributes instead, then each center (e.g., `km$centers[1,:]`, `km$centers[2,:]`) would be eighty values long and correspond to a point in eighty-dimensional space instead.

This is nice, because preserving the space allows us to interpret the clusters (e.g., these people are very wealthy, have high blood pressure, etc) and lets us assign new examples to the existing clusters. However, it's tricky to actually visualize something with $>3$ dimensions, so `plotcluster` projects down to a more tractable two dimensions, which can easily be plotted.

My guess is that for matching purposes, you should go with the original centers, rather than the ones given by `plotcluster`. However, if you really want those, it looks like `plotcluster` calls `discrproj` internally, so you could do that yourself.

Links:

- [FPC Package Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/fpc.pdf), where I read about `plotcluster` and `discrproj`
- [K Means Documentation (R)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html)

Comment: The reason why I want to match on the 2D coordinates is because I want to essentially click on any point in the plot and then based off of a 2D coordinate mapping, retrieve the data related to that point.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus If your data has more than 2 dimensions (more than 2 variables), this may not be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure it's totally impossible (unless multiple points end up projected onto the same coordinates, but you might have that problem in the original space too). Use discrproj to project your original data down to 2 dimensions, stash the resulting x,y coordinates somewhere and use them to look up mouse-clicks later.


You might consider drawing the actual row/example numbers at each point, then coloring them according to which cluster they "belong to". Couple that with a table of (row ID, attrib values) and it's easy to browse your data, but this breaks down with lots of examples/classes.

Comment: @Matt Krause: I believe that R's `identify` function requires the coordinates of the points, so if you calculate the x,y with `discproj`, you can feed them to `identify` to get back the actual point number.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to use `discrproj` to compute the 2D points in the plot? Checkout these other questions I posted as an extension to this question: [discrproj parameter](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51858/r-interpretation-of-parameter-to-discrproj), [2D coordinates](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51856/r-getting-2d-coordinates-from-kmeans), [identify function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327931/r-identify-function-in-cluster-plot)

Comment: @MattKrause It is okay if a few of the points are mapped to the same coordinate. As long as I get most of them, it is okay.

Answer (score 4):

If the `kmeans` function in base is an option, this will work:

```
# prepare data (from kmeans help)
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")

# calculate k-means
(cl <- kmeans(x, 5, nstart = 25))

# plot
plot(x, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:5, pch = 8)

# select points of interest
# returns row number of selected point
identify(x[,1], x[,2])
# click away on the plot... 
# then press escape to get the points

# find co-ords for selected point
# in this case, point at row 16
x[16,]
```

Comment: What do you mean "If the kmeans function in base is an option?"

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I am looking for! However, I am having trouble getting this to work with the dimensions of my data matrix which is 291 X 31. I cannot get the plot function to work. If you need a data sample, I can give you one.

Comment: I mean `stat::kmeans` might not be an option if you're using the `fpc` package for some functionality that is only in that package. If you paste in the output from `dput(mat2)` up there in your question then others can work with it also.

Comment: `fpc` is only for `plotcluster`. A 291 X 31 matrix is too large to post in my question. Perhaps I will extract a smaller piece of my matrix say a 29 X 5 matrix. In the meantime though, What does `col = cl$cluster` in your call to plot do?

Comment: `col = cl$cluster` sets the colour of the points in the plot so that points in the same cluster are plotted with the same colour.

Comment: Since my matrix has more than 2 columns, `plot` will place the first column on the x-axis and the second column on the y-axis. This would not be an accurate clustering... Any ideas? I thought about projecting the 31 dimensional coordinates into 2 dimensional coordinates, but I still do not know how to compute this projection.

Comment: `PCA` (principle components analysis) is a common method for reducing high dimension data to 2 dimensions for plotting clusters. Have you tried that? Lots of info here and elsewhere online.

Comment: Thanks so much! With my last edit, I have pretty much reduced my problem down to a solution that your answer will solve. I am doing some testing to see if it is correct.

Comment: Very creative solution! You should post that as a separate answer to your question and mark it as correct for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 4):

`identify` does not work with the plot given by `plotcluster`. So to counteract this we need to get the 2 dimensional coordinates that `plotcluster` is using. In the documentation it is given that `plotcluster` uses `discrproj$proj` to get 2 dimensional coordinates. So to get the identical plot that uses `plot` do the following:

```
plot(discrproj(t(mat2), km$cluster)$proj, col = km$cluster)
```

To get `identify` to work do:

```
 identify(discrproj(t(mat2), km$cluster)$proj, col = km$cluster)
```

Now, we can click the points in the plot, and the corresponding row will be given.